# Can kafka connect - mongo source run as cluster (max.tasks > 1)

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using the following [mongo-source](https://docs.mongodb.com/kafka-connector/current/kafka-source/) which is supported by kafka-connect.
I found that one of the configurations of the mongo source (from [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-kafka/blob/master/config/MongoSourceConnector.properties)) is *tasks.max*.

this means I can provide the connector tasks.max which is > 1, but I fail to understand what it will do behind the scene?

If it will create multiple connectors to listen to mongoDb change stream, then I will end up with duplicate messages. So, does mongo-source really has parallelism and works as a cluster? what does it do if it has more then 1 tasks.max?

Comment: How do we run that source file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mongo-source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-kafka)  doesn't support tasks.max > 1. Even if you set it greater than 1 only **one** task will be pulling data from mongo to Kafka.

How many task is created depends on particular connector. Function `List<Map<String, String>> Connector::taskConfigs(int maxTasks)`, (that should be overridden during the implementation of your connector) return the list, which size determine number of Tasks.
If you check mongo-kafka source connector you will see, that it is singletonList.

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-kafka/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mongodb/kafka/connect/MongoSourceConnector.java#L47

Comment: I wonder why nothing is written in documentation, and figure by only by accessing the code.